# Fully migrate Fabric to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, crashlytics, google-fabric

If I remove the Fabric plugin and keep integrated with Crashlytics via Firebase, will it also stop tracking the crashes? I've already linked and migrated to Firebase on the Fabric console.

I want to do this because after updating the gradle version, I get the following warning:

```
API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning has been resolved in the latest version of the Fabric plugin.